# What is the process of recognition the RPM package latest version in RPM repository?

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

I'm just trying to figure out how RPM recognizes the latest version of some package.
Say I have:

```
package-0.1-SNAPSHOT201212031
package-0.2-SNAPSHOT201212030
```

Will rpm manager compare it just as strings or there're some more logic behind it?
Or another example: will it recognize that 0.10.1 is newer than 0.1.1? (string comparison wouldn't help here).

Answer (score 1):

The only hard and fast rule is there there can be **no dashes** in the RELEASE field.

Consider:

```
rpm -qi hwdata
```

followed by

```
$ rpm -q hwdata --queryformat '%10{NAME} %20{VERSION} %20{RELEASE} %20{ARCH}\n'
hwdata             0.213.22                1.el5               noarch
```

See [The Release Tag](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html) section of this doc for reference on the release tags rules.

Note: for reference, sometimes I programmatic-ly stuff things into the rpm description if there is no [rpm-tag](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-queryformat-tags.html) for it in the specfile. Your mileage may vary, and I am not recommending this for packages destine to be back in the community as it is awkward. Just pointing it out as a workaround to keep from braking the various tools that operate on rpm's.

Note2: it is a common practice to use revision-control numbers in the RELEASE field. While this breaks from the rpm convention a bit. ( modifying that field, implies that the specfile changed... not the contents) It is a handy field to use because it does not break any rpm tools, and provides you with direct reference to the contents version. Also... if you have rpm contents checked-into a revision control system, this is already stepping outside of the rpm model a bit anyway. I.E. source rpm's become unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I've been trying get this nailed down and thought I'd share what is working form me.
I'm using a ruby script with an extension to the String class.

```
class String
  def explode
    self.split(/-|_|\./).collect {|i| if i == "0" || i.to_i > 0; then i = i.to_i; end; i}
  end
end
```

This breaks a given string into an array where a group of numbers are converted into a sortable numeric value (rather than being left as a string).

For example:

```
ruby -r./string_ext.rb -e ' puts %Q{package-0.1-SNAPSHOT201212031}.explode.inspect'
#=> ["package", 0, 1, "SNAPSHOT201212031"]

ruby -r./string_ext.rb -e ' puts %Q{package-0.2-SNAPSHOT201212031}.explode.inspect'
#=> ["package", 0, 2, "SNAPSHOT201212031"]

# the comparison of the resulting arrays is then very straight forward
ruby -r./string_ext.rb -e ' puts %Q{package-0.1-SNAPSHOT201212031}.explode <=> %Q{package-0.2-SNAPSHOT201212030}.explode'
#=> -1
```

Where -1 means that the first item is less than the second, 0 means they are equal, and 1 means that the second item is less than the first.

```
1 <=> 2 #=> -1
2 <=> 2 #=> 0
3 <=> 2 #=> 1
```

Using this approach it is pretty simple to collect the greatest value from an array of similar items (like an array of rpms associated with the same package).